# webpack 1 build peerDependencies cannot be found

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, jsx

I have a Rails app that includes a number of react components on the front end and recently while attempting to add another things started to break because of multiple versions of react.

Going back and updating old code so that all can be on `react@15.x` I decided to use peerDependencies so that every feature wasn't loading in it's own instance of the react library.

In development `peerDependencies` is working fine but when attempting to build for production I get the error:

```
Cannot resolve module 'react' in /Users/path/to/project/lib/toaster @ ...
```

What am I missing?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  // ... omitted ...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=development testem ci",
    "testem": "testem -g",
    "start": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack -p --config ./webpack.production.config.js --progress --profile --colors --preserve-symlinks"
  },
  "repository": { // ... omitted ... },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.4.5",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.17.2",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.3",
    "bundle-collapser": "^1.1.1",
    "del": "^1.1.1",
    "envify": "^3.2.0",
    "es6-promise": "^2.0.1",
    "tape": "^4.0.0",
    "testem": "^0.6.35",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "empty": "^0.10.0",
    "lodash": "^3.9.1",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.4.2"
  }
}
```

webpack.production.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    ...
  ],
  devtool: 'eval',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "output"),
    filename: 'index.js',
    library: 'my-package',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    modules: ['..', 'node_modules']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      // This has effect on the react lib size.
      "process.env": {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production")
      }
    }),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/vertx/),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/configs/),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/un~$/),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

This had nothing to do with `peerDependencies`. The problem was in my *webpack.production.config.js* file under `resolve`

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
}
```

needed to be

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
}
```

Which it was in my normal *webpack.config.js* file